# Fedora 37 Infinite boot on kernel 6.1.9-200 (and higher)

Tags: linux, fedora, kernel, linux-kernel

Fedora Linux 37 (Workstation Edition) x86_64
GNOME 43.2
Kernel: 6.1.7-200.fc37.x86_64

After selecting kernel 6.1.9 while boot (which is chosen by default) I'm having infinite black screen with blinking underline cursor at the top left. After choosing kernel 6.1.7 this screen lefts for 3-4 seconds and then boot continues as normal.

This problem appeared after sleep mode for some reason couldn't turn off on my laptop (model is Lenovo Legion 5 15ACH6A-82NW). I closed the laptop, sleep mode as usually turned on, then I opened it and sleep mode hadn't turned off (short click on power button that usually toggles sleep mode also didn't work), then I turned off it by long press on it and after it i can only boot normally with selecting kernel 6.1.7 on boot.

Any ideas why?

UPD: Fedora just automatically updated to kernel 6.1.10, and with it I also can't boot (infinite load)
UPD2: Same with 6.1.11 and 6.1.13

Comment: I just had similar problems with kernel 6.1.9 on my desktop system. The just released kernel 6.1.10 solved the problems.

Comment: I tried to boot on 6.0.7-301.fc37.x86_64 and kernel-devel successfully installed.
With 6.1.9 i still can't boot with same issue after reinstalling it

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [bodhi.fedoraproject.org](https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/?packages=kernel&release=F37) and download the desired version manually as rpm. Then install it via `sudo dnf install kernel-6.1.6*`