# Disable autoremove of old kernel versions on Fedora 37

Tags: boot, fedora, kernel, linux-kernel

Somewhy i can't boot on kernel version higher than 6.0.7-301 (more [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1767544/fedora-37-infinite-boot-on-kernel-6-1-9-200)).
Recently Fedora automatically downloaded kernel 6.1.10, and after a few days 6.1.11. Both of them, as i said, i can't use for boot. In menu, where I select a kernel version, there is always a 3 options.

Earlier, before kernel 6.1.10 and 6.1.11 was installed, i had 6.1.7 and 6.1.9, and now they are deleted. So, as i expect, after kernel 6.1.12 will be installed, 6.0.7 will be deleted automatically and i will have no opportunity to boot (if after release of 6.1.12 the problem will not be solved).

Also, It will be useful for me to know what could I do if 6.0.7 will be anyway deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either [lock the kernel](https://robbinespu.gitlab.io/posts/locking-package-fedora/), preventing updates (replace `6.0.7-301.fc30` with *your* specific version, e.g.  6.0.7-301.fc37.x86_64):

```
sudo dnf versionlock add kernel-6.0.7-301.fc37
```

Or [disable kernel updates](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/howto-prevent-kernel-updates/3001/2):

```
sudo dnf update --exclude=kernel*
```

That said, you might try to reinstall Fedora -- 37 seems to be the current version, at this time, and *should* work with latest kernel.

As for, "what could I do if 6.0.7 will be anyway deleted," **use dd to make a disk image**. You can can recover from almost *any* new issue by restoring a recent image.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!